# Why does the Spring MVC FlashMapManager require a HttpServletResponse to manage FlashMap instances?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have just finished refactoring a Spring Boot project to use the `FlashMapManager` to internally manage the messages indicating something was successful, where before the project used a vague "mode" parameter that was used to infer intent on pages with that parameter. I have to manually manage my `FlashMap`s and can't simply use `FlashAttributes` or `RedirectAttributes` because there are many pages that use modal dialog screens to create or edit entities and then redirect using Javascript, so I had to explicitly say the page that each `FlashMap` was intended for.

One thing that made this refactor troublesome was that in order to use the `FlashMapManager` properly, I needed to include `HttpServletResponse` objects every time I stored or read a `FlashMap` from the session, objects I rarely included as a method parameter in my endpoint methods, which meant most of my POST endpoints needed to change. However, looking at the source code for the `FlashMapManager` and the related subclasses, it does not appear like this `HttpServletResponse` parameter is ever used in the `AbstractFlashMapManager` or the `SessionFlashMapManager`. If this parameter isn't used, why do I need to include it? It feels inefficient and counterintuitive to have to include this parameter every time if it's not needed.

Comment: You aren't using and the default isn't but a custom other implementation might be using it. You could implement a `FlashMapManager` which would utilize cookies to store the state instead of the `Session`, for this you would need the response. I fail to see why you couldn't use the default, as there still is a post from the model dialog, the flashmap is stored in the session so the next one could simply retrieve it.

Comment: @M.Deinum I assumed that the default that you recommend (using RedirectAttributes) only works when using server-side redirects using return redirect:/url, but in this case the redirects are done by manipulating window.location with Javascript, and I don't think RedirectAttributes work in that case.

Comment: The redirect happens after doing something on the server, so as long as the flashmap is stored in the session the next request should be able to retrieve it. I do assume you are making an ajax post to a controller.